# Where is System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.EntityFramework DLL?

Tags: .net, silverlight, wcf-ria-services, domainservices

I'm trying to use RIA services, I installed Silverlight 4 and Silverlight 4 Tools/SDK, but I cannot setup a LINQToEntitiesDomainService because I can't find this namespace/assembly: System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.EntityFramework.  Where does this assembly come from, not sure why it's missing?  Is that an add-on I'm missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should find it in:-

> Program Files[ (x86)]\Microsoft SDKs\RIA Services\v1.0\Libraries\Server

As the folder suggests this is a server-side dll; if you are attempting to add to your Silverlight project then that would be the problem.  Its designed to be referenced by the Web project or a library project that is reference by the web project.

Comment: Yes, I plan to do that.  Thanks much for the direction :-)

Comment: Note: I had to add an additional dll from this directory: System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.dll

Answer (score 2):

A newer version of this is also part of the RIA Services Toolkit, in particular the NuGet package "RIA Services for EntityFramework Code-First (DbContext)". Needed if you want to use a newer version of EF.